# How to display all tabBar titles in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Basically i cant get to display all tabBar Items when i run my app, just the first view controller is displayed:

[image]

I literally have to click on a tab to display its Item:

[image]

This my code in Appdelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Initialize window
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    // Set background colors for both NavBar and TabBar
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.157 green:0.718 blue:0.553 alpha:1]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.141 green:0.216 blue:0.263 alpha:1]];

    // Initialize your five tab controllers.  with each tab has its own navigation controller
    HomePageView *homePageView = [[HomePageView alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homePageView];

    ProfileViewController *profileViewController=[[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:profileViewController];

    FeedViewController *feedViewController=[[FeedViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:feedViewController];

    ListeningSessionViewController *listeningSessionViewController= [[ListeningSessionViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listeningSessionViewController];

    RecievedViewController *recievedViewController =[[RecievedViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav5 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:recievedViewController];

    // initialize tabbarcontroller,set your viewcontrollers and change its color.
    self.tabC = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5, nil];
    [self.tabC setViewControllers: controllers animated:NO];
    [_window addSubview:self.tabC.view];

    // Show window
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the tab bar item titles now?  Also, you shouldn't use addSubview to add the tab bar controller, you should be setting the tab bar controller as the root view controller of the window.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you, I am adding the titles in its individual viewcontoller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're setting the titles in the viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear methods of the controllers. That won't work, because, while all the controllers are instantiated in the app delegate, only the controller at index 0 has its view loaded, and thus viewDidLoad will not be run for the other controllers. Instead, you should set the titles on the navigation controllers in the app delegate,

```
ProfileViewController *profileViewController=[[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:profileViewController];
nav2.tabBarItem.title = @"Profile";
```

Comment: thank you rdelmar ! I was just being stupid, that was pretty obvious :D